# Sparx EA Heatmap: Combine none or multiple results from a selects subquery into a single comma-separated value

Tags: sql

I'm using Sparx EA 14.x with the file based repository, and moving into SQL server based soon. Currently creating some base template level model, to be used later with real customer data with SQL server based repository. 
I have created Tagged Values (type=RefGUIDList) for e.g. adding relation into existing Bus.Processes in my data elemets. The list of existing business processes can be selected and their .ea_guid is stored in the tagged value as value.

I have created an HeatMap chart, with attached sql.

The sql works fine if the tagged value has only one business process selected, the problem is that if I add more processes there is no results.

```
 SELECT (SELECT t_object.Name FROM t_object
         WHERE t_object.ea_guid = tv.Value) AS Series,
        t_object.Alias AS GroupName, Packages.Name 
 FROM t_object,
      t_package RootPackage,
      t_package Packages, 
      t_objectproperties tv 
 WHERE RootPackage.Name = 'Data elements' AND 
       Packages.Parent_ID = RootPackage.Package_ID AND 
       t_object.Package_ID = Packages.Package_ID AND 
       t_object.Object_ID = tv.Object_ID AND 
       tv.Property = 'APM:Prosesses'
```

One solution, that I have been looking, would be to concatenate the listed Bus.processes names and show the result.

I'm aware that the SQL server dialect is different than the current Access based repository.

Comment: Hint of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and **easier to convert to outer join** if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the Sparx t_objectproperties.ea_guid was stored in several times into t_objectproperties.Value and I did need the corresponding t_object.Name as comma concatenated.

In my case worked a solution, where I 1st moved the repository into SQL server based repository and did create a function like below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnSplitString  
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(1000), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
 ) 
 RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) AS  
 BEGIN 
    DECLARE @csvObjectname VARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
      IF @end = 0  
        SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1
      SELECT @csvObjectname = COALESCE(@csvObjectname + ', ', '') +
            COALESCE(t_Object.Name,'')
      FROM t_Object
        WHERE t_Object.ea_guid = SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start) 
      SET @start = @end + 1 
      SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

  END 
  RETURN @csvObjectname
END
```